# AttributeError: 'area' object has no attribute 'radius'

Tags: python, class, typeclass

I'm new baby in Python and having the following error can you guys look into it........................................
AttributeError: 'area' object has no attribute 'radius'. So, I'm facing error in any cases. Thank for help

```py
import math, random


class area:
    def __init__(self, radius, length, breath, height, base):
        if radius == 0 and breath != 0:
            self.radius = random.uniform(1.1, 9.5)
            self.length = random.uniform(10.5, 15.5)
            self.breath = random.uniform(15, 20)
            self.height = random.uniform(20, 25)
            self.base = random.uniform(26, 32)
        elif length == 0 and heigh != 0:
            self.radius = random.uniform(1.1, 9.5)
            self.length = length
            self.breath = random.uniform(15, 20)
            self.height = height
            self.base = base
        elif height == 0 and base != 0:
            self.radius = radius
            self.length = random.uniform(1.1, 9.5)
            self.breath = breath
            self.height = random.uniform(1.1, 9.5)
            self.base = base

    def areaofcircle(self):
        return (self.radius ** 2) * math.pi

    def areaoftriangl(self):
        return 0.5 * (self.height) * (self.base)

    def areaofrectangle(self):
        return (self.length) * (self.breath)


areas = []
for i in range(0, 10):
    v = area(1, 3, 5, 0, 0)
    areas.append(v)

for v in areas:
    print(
        "Area of Circle:",
        v.areaofcircle(),
        "Area of Triangle:",
        v.areaoftriangl(),
        "Area of Rectangle:",
        v.areaofrectangle(),
    )
```

Comment: Your `areaofcircle(self, radius)` has an extra parameter `radius` that you do not use. You should probably remove it.

Comment: Beyond @khelwood's comment, there are also cases where you end up not initializing anything in `__init__`, especially since you're comparing ` == 0` and the defaults are `None`...

Comment: As additional code review commentary, I find it hard to visualize what sort of object the `area` class represents – if you don't pass anything in, it might initialize itself entirely randomly, maybe?, and you can measure its area as it were a circle, a triangle, or a rectangle? Should you maybe have subclasses for the various geometric shapes?

Comment: @khelwood I did remove the radius but as mentioned in the question it again shows an error  AttributeError: 'area' object has no attribute 'radius'

Comment: @Shane Yes, that's a different problem with your code. See AKX's comments.

Comment: @AKX, can you bit elaborate it what do you mean by subclass??

Comment: No, that's beyond the scope of this question. Google for Python subclasses; there are plenty of tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to remove radius from this function arguments

```
def areaofcircle(self, radius):
            return (self.radius ** 2) * math.pi
```

to be:

```
def areaofcircle(self):
            return (self.radius ** 2) * math.pi
```

Comment: Thanks for the help however,  I did remove the radius as you said but as mentioned in the question it again shows an error AttributeError: 'area' object has no attribute 'radius'

Answer (score 0):

By defining the function as

```
def areaofcircle(self, radius)
```

Your function expect two inputs, but in your case you only give one. As far as I understand 'radius' is a datafield of the area class. Therefore, you can call it with "self.radius". In this case if you remove the radius parameter from the function, it should all work out.

```
def areaofcircle(self)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, however, I did remove the radius as you said but still it shows an error AttributeError: 'area' object has no attribute 'radius'

Comment: If the area class doesn't have a variable named radius it is normal, self.radius calls the 'radius' variable of the class itself. You should define a new variable named 'radius 'above the functions.